# How to set pen width of rivers based on scalerank attribute (QGis 2.2)?

Tags: vector, symbology, qgis-2.2

I have a Vectorlayer from NaturalEarth.com with riverdata that includes "scalerank" information. Now I want to display these with different pen width  based on their scalerank, like this:

scalerank 1 = 0,5 mm pen width

scalerank 2 = 0,3 mm

and so on.

I guess you do this in the Layer Properties. I selected the "Simple Line" and opened the "data defined properties". Here I selected "pen width" to the left, under "field" i selected "scalerank" and then I don´t know how to build the expression. Were my steps even correct up to this point? It would be really great if someone could describe in detail how I would proceed or point me towards a simple guide for beginners. 
I already read through the "Symbology" and "Classification" Chapter of the Training manual but they focus on the fill element there :(

Comment: How many scale ranks do you have?

Comment: Scaleranks range from 1 to 6 und the explicit value is also 1, 2,...,6